# select top 10 for each rownumber

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-server-2014, window-functions

Query #1 returns thousands of rows for each skid. I like to know if there is a faster way select only top 10 for each skid. query #2 is slow. Is there is any way I can optimize in query #1 to make it faster?

query #1

```
select skid, date_run, price, ROW_NUMBER()over(PARTITION BY 
skid ORDER BY date_run ASC) as rowid 
from stocktrack where rsi is null
```

query #2

```
with ctevalue
(select skid, date_run, price, ROW_NUMBER()over(PARTITION BY 
skid ORDER BY date_run ASC) as rowid 
from stocktrack where rsi is null
)
select skid, date_run rowid
from ctevalue
where rowid < 11
```

Comment: What does the execution plan look like? What indexes do you have on the stocktrack table?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
select 
  * 
from
  (select 
    skid, date_run, price, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY skid ORDER BY date_run ASC) as rowid 
  from 
    stocktrack where rsi is null) data
where
  data.rowid < 11
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Could you please try this query with the execution plan enabled to see if SQL Server recommends any additional index?  I think it can be improved with an index.  BTW, how many records are you retrieving?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cross apply`:

```
select st.skid, st.date_run, st.price
from sktable sk cross apply
     (select top 10 st.*
      from stocktrack st2
      where st2.skid = sk.skid and
      order by date_run asc
     ) st
```

along with an index on `stocktrack(skid, date_run, price)`.

The first table is wherever the `skid` is referring to.  If necessary, you could try `(select distinct skid from stocktrack st)`.